# Esri Maps for SharePoint installation hangs?

Tags: installation, sharepoint, esri-maps-sharepoint

We're trying to install Esri Maps for SharePoint 4.0 using [the installation guide](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/maps-for-sharepoint/foundation-server/install-and-configure/install-em4sp.htm)'s PowerShell commands.

The guide has the following commands:

```
    Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath C:\Software\ESRI.ArcGIS.Mapping.SharePoint.wsp
Install-SPSolution ESRI.ArcGIS.Mapping.SharePoint.wsp -WebApplication http://<web application name> -GACDeployment
Enable-SPFeature -identity "ESRI.ArcGIS.Mapping.SharePoint.wsp13_ArcGIS Map WebPart" -URL http://<web application name>/sites/MySiteCollectionName
WebContentInstaller.ps1 -install
UpdateCustomBCSConnectors.ps1 –ServiceContext http://<web application name>/sites/MySiteCollectionName
```

Note well - this is a poor installation approach, as it should wait for the install to complete before enabling the feature.

The Install-SPSolution command hangs forever, or at least for an hour.

I'm guessing that the solution has an event receiver within it that tries to contact ESRI (why it would do that during a solution install I don't know), however I can't be sure.  Because of our firewall setup this request hangs forever - essentially freezing the install.

Am I on the right track here, or is there another solution to this?  At this stage it's looking like we have to:

1. Identify what site it's trying to access
2. Create a new hosts file entry denying access rather than freezing with the Firewall

Comment: I suppose you're talking about Esri Maps for Sharepoint? There is no version 4 of ArcGIS. If you have a maintenance contract with Esri, you can contact their support directly.

Comment: "ESRI people - where are you ?" http://support.esri.com/

Comment: Is there any useful diagnostic information in the [SharePoint ULS logs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210652.aspx) when Install-SPSolution is running?

Comment: In part this is a placeholder for other people with the same issue.  I've started the (long) process of going through ESRI support.

- The specific version is : Esri_Maps_SharePoint_4_0_SP2013.zip, so I think a version 4 version does exist.

Answer (score 1):

Try unblocking the setup.exe file.  In our environment, since the file came from the internet, it was blocked, and as a result could not be unpacked.  Right click on the setup.exe file, properties, then click "unblock"